# Can we use delta command to get a difference between current & previous value which have the same unique id?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to find a difference between current & previous value of AOV (Avg value) which have the same unique ID (country). Right now my query gets the difference but doesn't respect the unique IDs. Any help or suggestion would be great!!

Query

```
index=test source=orders_prd_*
| dedup message.orderNo
| bin _time span=1h
| stats avg(message.orderTotal) as AOV by country _time | delta AOV AS Diff | eval OrderPercentage=(((Diff)/AOV)*100)
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Try `streamstats` in place of `delta`.  With a window of 2 events, the `range` function is the same as `delta`.

```
index=test source=orders_prd_*
| dedup message.orderNo
| bin _time span=1h
| stats avg(message.orderTotal) as AOV by country _time 
| streamstats window=2 range(AOV) AS Diff by country
| eval OrderPercentage=(((Diff)/AOV)*100)
```

Since `range` is not giving the desired results, you can use delta, but you'll have to jump through some hoops to respect country changes.

````
index=test source=orders_prd_*
| dedup message.orderNo
| bin _time span=1h
| stats avg(message.orderTotal) as AOV by country _time
| delta AOV AS Diff 
```Count the results by country.```
| streamstats reset_on_change=1 count by country
```When the count is 1 then we have a new country
   so clear the Diff field.```
| eval Diff=if(count==1, null(), Diff)
| eval OrderPercentage=(((Diff)/AOV)*100)
| fields - count
````

Comment: Ahh gotcha that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: The issue I see with 'range' function is it's giving the absolute value and not respecting the difference as '+' or '-' integer which blows my % calculation. My idea around this alert is to trigger when the Order% is over or under a certain value compared to its previous value.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Try the second query in my revised answer.